# How do I force zeep to use only TLSv1.2?

Tags: python-2.7, zeep

I'm designing a SOAP client using python and SOAP server I'm connecting to only allows TLSv1.2. I looked up in `zeep` documentation but couldn't find any setting where I can force it to use only 'TLSv1.2'. If zeep doesn't have this feature, are there any other SOAP python libraries with this feature ?

Comment: Isn't this automatic to TSL1.2 if the server supports it?

Comment: It seems like it is. I was using the faulty wsdl it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For default, zeep uses a TLS 1.2. But if you need to verify the TLS connection (in case you have a self-signed certificate for your host), the best way is to create a `requests.Session` instance and add the information to that `Session`, so it keeps persistent:

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.verify = 'path/to/my/certificate.pem'
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(
    'http://my.own.sslhost.local/service?WSDL',
    transport=transport)
```

Alternatively, instead of using `session.verify` you can use session.cert if you just want to use an TLS client certificate.

More information in: https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/transport.html

Comment: `session.cert` is just the client certificate for authentication